# How to rebuild left Table View of Settings app on iPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

How can I build a UITableView styled like in the iPad Settings app? I have already set an similar image as the background image. However, I have no idea how to add two border to a cell or how to change the text shadow on selection.

Best,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

iPad Settings app is a UISplitView app, not just a basic UITableView app.  UISplitView is a container containing two separate UIViewControllers, one for left pane, one for right.  They are linked to each other by implementing UISplitViewDelegate.  [UISplitViewController Class Reference](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) can provide you with more information.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this of course. I want to rebuild the styling of the Table View.

Comment: maybe, I didn't understand the question properly.  What exactly are you looking to duplicate from the Settings App?  Left pane of the UISplitView contains a tableview with style UITableViewStylePlain and the right pane contains a tableview with style UITableViewStyleGrouped.  What is it exactly that you are having hard time duplicating in your app?